# Problem with paramiko: Send a command to a terminal, it is executed, and the terminal executes it again in a new command send

Tags: python, paramiko

Good morning,

I am new to **Paramiko** and I am working with it. I have a problem, and I cannot find a solution.

The problem is that I must execute several commands in a row, I execute my first command and everything is fine. I get my data and do my treatment, but it happens that when I execute a second command, the channel continues to execute my first command, as if it were stored in a cache (it is the best description I can give), I show it below:

**I execute my first command:**

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) #Si no encuentra el host, lo agegra automaticamente
ssh.connect('xxxxxxxxxxx', username='xxxxxxxx', password='xxxxxxx.',port='22',timeout=500) #Iniciamos la conexion
shell=ssh.invoke_shell() 

shell.send('display interface description | include IP7'+'\n\r') #Envio mi comando

while count < 2:

    resp = shell.recv(9999)
#   print(resp)
    buff_string += str(resp,'utf-8',errors='ignore') 
#   print(buff_string)
    patron=re.compile(f'<{equipo}>') 
    result=patron.findall(buff_string)  
    count=len(result)  
#   print(count)

    if(count==1):
#         shell.send('screen-length 0 temporary'+'\n\r') 
        shell.send('display interface description | include IP7'+'\n\r') 

print('\n'+'La Primera Salida es:')
print(buff_string +'\n' )

<PNE5MCY01>display interface description | include IP7
PHY: Physical
*down: administratively down
^down: standby
(l): loopback
(s): spoofing
(E): E-Trunk down
(b): BFD down
(B): Bit-error-detection down
(e): ETHOAM down
(d): Dampening Suppressed
(p): port alarm down
(dl): DLDP down
(lh): link heartbeat down
Interface                     PHY     Protocol Description                     
GE1/2/7                       up      up       Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 1/1/5 (Servicio 1711 1Gbps) IP7BTO01 Gi7/0/0
GE1/2/8                       up      up       Conexion a IP7MCY01 Gi1/0/1     
GE1/2/9                       up      up       Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 2/1/6 (Servicio 608 1Gbps) IP7VAL01 Gi4/0/1
<PNE5MCY01>
```

**Now I will execute a second command and you get the following:**

```
res=''
count2=0;
cadena='';
shell.send('display ospf peer GigabitEthernet1/2/7 | i State'+'\n\r') #Envio mi comando

while count2 < 10:
    res = shell.recv(9999) 
#    print(resp)
    cadena += str(res,'utf-8',errors='ignore')
#   print(buff_string)
    patron=re.compile(f'<{equipo}>') 
    result2=patron.findall(cadena)  
    count2=len(result2)  
#   print(count)

    if(count2==1):  
           shell.send('display ospf peer GigabitEthernet1/2/7 

print(cadena)

<PNE5MCY01>display interface description | include IP7
PHY: Physical
*down: administratively down
^down: standby
(l): loopback
(s): spoofing
(E): E-Trunk down
(b): BFD down
(B): Bit-error-detection down
(e): ETHOAM down
(d): Dampening Suppressed
(p): port alarm down
(dl): DLDP down
(lh): link heartbeat down
Interface                     PHY     Protocol Description                     
GE1/2/7                       up      up       Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 1/1/5 (Servicio 1711 1Gbps) IP7BTO01 Gi7/0/0
GE1/2/8                       up      up       Conexion a IP7MCY01 Gi1/0/1     
GE1/2/9                       up      up       Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 2/1/6 (Servicio 608 1Gbps) IP7VAL01 Gi4/0/1
<PNE5MCY01>
<PNE5MCY01>display interface description | include IP7
PHY: Physical
*down: administratively down
^down: standby
(l): loopback
(s): spoofing
(E): E-Trunk down
(b): BFD down
(B): Bit-error-detection down
(e): ETHOAM down
(d): Dampening Suppressed
(p): port alarm down
(dl): DLDP down
(lh): link heartbeat down
Interface                     PHY     Protocol Description                     
GE1/2/7                       up      up       Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 1/1/5 (Servicio 1711 1Gbps) IP7BTO01 Gi7/0/0
GE1/2/8                       up      up       Conexion a IP7MCY01 Gi1/0/1     
GE1/2/9                       up      up       Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 2/1/6 (Servicio 608 1Gbps) IP7VAL01 Gi4/0/1
<PNE5MCY01>
<PNE5MCY01>display interface description | include IP7
PHY: Physical
*down: administratively down
^down: standby
(l): loopback
(s): spoofing
(E): E-Trunk down
(b): BFD down
(B): Bit-error-detection down
(e): ETHOAM down
(d): Dampening Suppressed
(p): port alarm down
(dl): DLDP down
(lh): link heartbeat down
Interface                     PHY     Protocol Description                     
GE1/2/7                       up      up       Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 1/1/5 (Servicio 1711 1Gbps) IP7BTO01 Gi7/0/0
GE1/2/8                       up      up       Conexion a IP7MCY01 Gi1/0/1     
GE1/2/9                       up      up       Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 2/1/6 (Servicio 608 1Gbps) IP7VAL01 Gi4/0/1
<PNE5MCY01>
<PNE5MCY01>display ospf peer GigabitEthernet1/2/7 | i State

          OSPF Process 100 with Router ID 10.18.219.39
                Neighbors

 Area 0.0.0.0 interface 10.53.209.13 (GE1/2/7)'s neighbors
   State: Full      Mode:Nbr is Master   Priority: 1
<PNE5MCY01>
```

As you can see when executing my second command, somehow I re-execute my first command, and only after having executed my first command a number of times, is it that I execute the last command.

The cycles (where) that are seen there are used to store the data, but I don't know if that influences, because it should happen that when executing my second command, the first one should not appear.

I was looking for information on the internet but I didn't find much, and I am very new in this **paramiko** topic

Comment: At the end of your send use '+ \r\n'` the `\r` goes before the `\n` so change it to '\r\n'`

Comment: Negative: Change it in the entire command you sent and follow the problem.

Comment: It looks like your execute the `display interface description | include IP7` command again in the `while count < 2:` loop

Comment: If I execute it because it is necessary to obtain the first response, it is not possible, but it should not interfere in the execution of the second command

Comment: I do not understand the first part of your comment. But in you execute the `display interface ...` command a second time, you cannot be surprised that you get the response second time as well.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by changing my code to receive my data, which helped me improve the response of my code, and the execution of the command no longer appears repeatedly.

Use [recv_ready](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.6/api/channel.html) to store my response, taking into account that after the command is executed, it should be given a [timeout](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time/sleep)

My code to store my first response was:

```
shell.send('display interface description | include PED'+'\r\n') 
sleep(1)                                        
 while shell.recv_ready() == True:                
       buff_string += str(shell.recv(9999),'utf-8',errors='ignore') 
       patron=re.compile(f'<{equipo}>')
       result=patron.findall(buff_string)
       count=len(result)                    
 #     print(count)                      
       if(count==1):                     
          shell.send('screen-length 0 temporary'+'\n\r')                          
          shell.send('display interface description | include PED'+'\r\n')  
          sleep(1)
```

The part of sending the command again if count == 1 is because although I send my command in the first instance, the terminal does not seem to respond in some moments, so I must execute it again, but in reality it is a code only for my case

And to get my second answer is the same process, execute recv_ready and place a respective waiting time for the response of the terminal.

I hope this helps others.